# Copy table row and return insert ID on PHP Programming with Oracle Database

Tags: php, oracle

I have a problem returning inserted id when copying data with auto increment id (PHP Programming with Oracle Database)

Here is the code :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Z_TBL_AD_PP PPA (PPA.ID,PPA.ORGID,PPA.VENDORID,PPA.START_DATE,PPA.STATUS) 
   SELECT '',PPB.ORGID,PPB.VENDORID,PPB.START_DATE,'1' 
   FROM Z_TBL_AD_PP PPB WHERE PPB.ID='$ppId' returning id into :id";

$stid = oci_parse($this->db_connect, $sql);

oci_bind_by_name($stid,":ID",$id,-1,OCI_B_INT);

$r = oci_execute($stid);

$inserted_id=$id;
```

Here is the error message:

> oci_execute(): ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: *"But Failed"* is no appropriate error description. What was the exact massage? What did you try to solve the issue? Have you read the docs? Please see [ask].

Comment: Also, are you using [oracle] or [mysql]. These are two different databases, and solutions may have different implementations.

Comment: @PaulKertscher : thank you for ur reply, here is the error : oci_execute(): ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @APC : PHP programming using Oracle Database. Error : oci_execute(): ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @AntonSujarwo please **edit** your question and add the error message there.

Comment: @PaulKertscher : Done, thank you for ur advice

Comment: You need to post your whole code. The Oracle code on its own is the correct syntax so most likely your problem is the way you're embedding it in PHP.

Comment: @APC : done. Do u have any solution for this problem?

Comment: @PaulKertscher : any solution?